# Back button shows half on custom navigation bar iPad

Tags: ipad

The back button on custom navigation bar shows half on iPad, it shows properly on iPhone. app supports only portrait mode.

[image]

source code,

```
  UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
if (isPad) {
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 70);
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonUnpressed-iPad_120X70.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonPressed-iPad_120X70.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}else{
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35);
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonUnpressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonPressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
[buttonItem release]; buttonItem = nil;
```

Please help.

Comment: what happens when you set `backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,10,60,35)`?  I.E. change the X & Y parameters to the initial button frame,

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: I tried that as well, but it doesn't make any change. only thing changes is its height and width if you change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, posting the details here so it might be helpful to others

```
1] created a UIButton, with custom image.
2] created a UIView, which will fit properly on UINavigationbar.
3] added UIButton on UIView.
4] created UIBarButtonItem with custom view.
```

here is the code,

```
    if (isPad) {
        UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 200, 200)];
        UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 90, 120, 70);
        [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonUnpressed-iPad_120X70.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonPressed-iPad_120X70.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [customView addSubview:backButton];

        UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
        [customView release];  customView = nil;
        [buttonItem release]; buttonItem = nil;
    }else{
        UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35);
        [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonUnpressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButtonPressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
        [buttonItem release]; 
        buttonItem = nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, I just realized that you're trying to slam a UIButton control into a UIBarButtonItem via an initalizer that's expecting a basic UIView and not a control.

Don't do that!

Why not just create your bar button item via:

```
UIBarButtonItem * buttonItem = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" 
                                     style: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                    target: self 
                                    action: @selector(backButtonPressed:);
```

And let the O.S. handle the appropriate highlighting (if there is to be any).

Comment: actually I have a custom navigation bar, so default UIBarButtonItem will not look good on it.